# Converting DFA to NFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I'm doing a **practice exam question** which asks to convert a DFA to NFA.

My current thoughts about this question is that you need to add an empty transition to the diagram, but i'm not sure if this is the correct method, and if it is correct where would it go, after q1 or after q2. i don't fully understand the concept of converting to nfa to be honest.

[image]

Comment: Neither do I. And IMO a DFA may be considered as a NDFA.

Comment: Check the details of your textbook's definition of NFA. Perhaps it has some extra requirements such as "only $\varepsilon$-transitions out of the initial state" or "no transitions out of the accepting state"?